# REACT: How to swap elements in To Do list by their priorities

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing to do list and I want to make function that swap tasks by their priorities. For example:

1. Go to gym
2. Learn react

   I want to make button that move elements up and down and get:

   1. Learn react
   2. Go to gym

I have function that I'm pretty sure working correct but I think problem in <div> where I use this function

```
const moveUpDown = (currentIndex, nextIndex) =>{
  const newCounts = [...todos]

  const currentCounts = newCounts[currentIndex]
  const previousCounts = newCounts[nextIndex]

  newCounts[currentIndex] = previousCounts
  newCounts[nextIndex] = currentCounts

  setTodos(newCounts)
}
```

This is my return:

```
function ToDo(props) {
    return (
        <div key={props.todo} className="item-todo">
            <div 
                className={props.todo.complete ? "item-text strike" : "item-text"}
                onClick={() => props.toggleTask(props.todo.id)}
                >
                {props.todo.task}
            </div>
            <div className="item-delete" onClick={() => props.removeTask(props.todo.id)}>
                X
            </div>
// Lines below I'm using function moveUpDown
            <div
                className="item-moveUpDown" disabled = {props.todo === 0} onClick={() => props.moveUpDown(props.todo, props.todo - 1)}
                >
                Up
            </div>
            <div
                className="item-moveUpDown" disabled = {props.todo === 0} onClick={() => props.moveUpDown(props.todo, props.todo + 1)}
            >
                Down
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters you're passing to `moveUpDown` don't make sense - it looks like they should be numbers, but you're passing `props.todo` which is an object.

Maybe if you changed the `moveUpDown` function to accept the "to do" you want to move, and a delta to indicate which direction you wanted to move it; eg:

```js
const moveUpDown = (todo, delta) =>{
  const newCounts = [...todos];

  // Remove from the array
  const currentIndex = newCounts.indexOf(todo);
  newCounts.splice(currentIndex, 1);

  // Now put it back in at the new position
  newCounts.splice(currentIndex + delta, 0, todo);

  setTodos(newCounts)
}
```

Now you can change your callers, eg:

```
<div
    className="item-moveUpDown"
    disabled={props.todo === 0}
    onClick={() => props.moveUpDown(props.todo, 1)}
>
    Down
</div>
```

Note also that your `disabled` attribute doesn't make sense - `props.todo` is an object so it will never be equal to zero. Perhaps you should be passing the index of the todo item as a separate property?